# How to pass contents in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS rather than file path?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-iam, google-secret-manager

Is there any way to use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable and pass the contents of the file to it rather than path to file, actually I want to use service account from my NodeJs application but my condition is I can't use it through the file but I can pass it contents through my NodeJS code.

Comment: Do you want your NodeJS code to be available as content of GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable within a Pod ?

Comment: yes I want to use content generated by my NodeJS code in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Comment: Where is this content generated ? Is it available before the Pod starts ?

Answer (score 2):

If you’re on GKE, you should use workload identity instead of passing in a service account credential. This is the more secure and preferred way.

Outside of GKE/GCP, you can build a custom auth client:

```
const creds = JSON.parse(process.env.GOOGLE_CREDS);
this.auth = new GoogleAuth({
  scopes: [...],
  credentials: creds,
});
```